# how to pass local variable to a linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have the following code in which I am passing a local variable to a linq query for a specific record, after that record I want to check whether there is a record according to that id or not.

First it gives me the error "`Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool`"

Second if I want to count the rows in this query or want to check whether there is a row or not, how will I do that, here is my code:

```
int J_Job_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["J_Job_ID"]);
        //Check If this ID exists in the database
        var query = from m in JE.J_Posted_Jobs_Tbl
                    where m.J_Job_ID = Convert.ToInt32(J_Job_ID)
                    select m;
```

Comment: Why do you convert J_Job_ID twice ?

Comment: Yeap my bad, i was actually removing that second conversion but forgot at the end when posted this thread, Thanks alot brothers walther and Alex

Comment: Can you guys plz answer my this question plz walther and Alex, it will be highly appreciated, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523277/how-to-show-multiple-records-in-asp-net-using-ef-linqthe-best-approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
where m.J_Job_ID == Convert.ToInt32(J_Job_ID)
```

as for count

```
query.Count()
```

Comment: Oh thats so nice, i am using equality operator instead of comparison, Thanks alot for correcting it Ondrej

Comment: Can you answer my this question plz Ondrej http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523277/how-to-show-multiple-records-in-asp-net-using-ef-linqthe-best-approach